# How to check if a MaskedTextBox is empty from a user input?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, validation, maskedtextbox

I'm using a `MaskedTextBox`, with the following short date `Mask`: "00/00/0000".
My problem is that I wanna know when the control is empty:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(maskedTextBox1.Text))
{
    DataTable dt = function.ViewOrders(Functions.GetEid);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
}
```

It's not working, when `maskedTextBox1` looks empty (and I'm sure it is), the `if` statement doesn't detect that it is `null` or `Empty`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
maskedTextBox1.MaskCompleted
```

Or

```
maskedTextBox1.MaskFull
```

properties to check if user has entered the complete mask input or not.

Comment: What if I want to check if the user entered anything, even if one character?

Comment: I couldn't get your question. You can get the text of textbox by `maskedTextBox1.Text`, so you will get whatever user has written in it.

Comment: this does not actually answer the question. Which is "how to know if it the control is EMPTY".The best way to do this is to remove the mask like the answer from @user3219570

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I would first remove the mask and then check the text like a normal textbox.

```
maskedTextBox.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;

//...Perform normal textbox validation
```

Answer (score 3):

I just faced this problem. I Needed the Masked Value, but also needed send empty string if the user didn't introduced any data in one single step.

I discovered the property 
[MaskedTextProvider.ToDisplayString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.maskedtextprovider.todisplaystring(v=vs.110).aspx) so I use the MaskedTextbox with:

```
maskedTextBox.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
```

BUT I always read the text from:

```
maskedTextBox.MaskedTextProvider.ToDisplayString()
```

This way, if the user has not introduced text in the control Text property will be empty:

```
maskedTextBox.Text == string.Empty
```

And when you detect the string is not empty you can use the full text including literals for example:

```
DoSomething((maskedTextBox.Text == string.Empty) ? maskedTextBox.Text: maskedTextBox.MaskedTextProvider.ToDisplayString());
```

or

```
DoSomething((maskedTextBox.Text == string.Empty) ? string.Empty: maskedTextBox.MaskedTextProvider.ToDisplayString());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set the property maskedTextBox.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals then the TypeValidationCompleted event validation will not work. To test if the short date maskedtextbox is empty you could just use:

```
        if (maskedTextBox1.Text == "  /  /")
        {
            ...;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try trim.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(maskedTextBox.Text.Trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

What logic are you trying to accomplish with the if statement? As it is right know, you are saying:
If the textbox is empty, set source of datagridview2 + to ViewOrder data. I'm not sure what your trying to do but I think you want the info to load if you have a date. to fix this all you have to do is add ! in the if statement which would make the if statement mean, if there is text in textbox then run code.

```
if( !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(maskedTextBox2.Text)))
```

Comment: i wanna make if statement to do if the masked text box is empty do something else do another something and by the way the masked text box have a mask = "00/00/0000" (Short Date)

Comment: @MuhammedSalah What do you mean by `Empty`? Do you mean by `Empty` that `textbox` should have only `mask` but the user input `value`?

Comment: @Shaharyar Yup Exactly that 's what i need :)

Comment: I dont have my computer infront of me to try it but look into MaskComplete and MaskFull properties for MaskedTextBox. MaskCompleted checks only required input elements. To determine whether all required and optional input elements have been filled in, use the MaskFull property instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Telerik masked textbox which does not have MaskCompleted or MaskFull, a tricky solution would be this:

the mask always contain a charachter like this: `"_"` we check masked text box by this:

```
if (textbox1.Text.Contains("_"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct numbers!","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            return;
        }
```

if the text box is full, then it does not contain `"_"`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MaskedTextBox, (MTB), using the mask “00/00/0000” is an incorrect string to use for testing its emptiness. This is because the MTB is not like a normal textbox, and the short date mask must be used to determine its string value.
Let’s assume you have a MTB name mskDateOfBirth on your form. In order to test its emptiness, a statement like the following is needed

```
if (mskDateOfBirth.MaskedTextProvider.ToDisplayString() == "__/__/____")
{
    // Do something when true
}   
else
{
    // Do something when false          
}
```

I have tested this out using Visual Studio 2019 and it works fine.  Hope this is helpful.

Comment: For some reason the Stackflow word process, is condensing the undercores. Mask should look like "__/__/____"

Comment: The Answer field accepts markup; use the <code> tag or the formatting buttons above the field to format code.

Comment: By the way, this can fail if the user has a non-standard system-level date format. For example, my machine is set to a `yyyy-MM-dd` format, which has a mask of `____-__-__`, which would fail the conditional check (even though it's empty).

Answer (score -1):

If the empty value is "  /  /", declare a constant for it:

```
const string EmptyDateInput = "  /  /";
```

And then later you can repeatedly use it to compare:

```
if (maskedTextBox1.Text == EmptyDateInput)
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I test this concept and was success in in the following syntax

```
if( maskedtextbox_name.MaskkedTextProvider.ToDisplayString() == "__-__-____")
{
  // Your function;
}
```